# Inserting column data into an already created table SQL

Tags: sql

For example I created a data of transactions and included names, location, and ID. Now I created another column saying date. How would I update each individually and include a date for each?

So this was my table before

[image]

and now this is my table after

[image]

How do I add information to the transaction date to lets say TransactionID 12?

Comment: Provide more information please.

Comment: use update from join

Comment: Sure, I updated the original question

Answer (score 0):

```
update MSTransaction
set TransactionDate = ('2015-12-17')
where TransactionID = 12
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the t-sql syntax

```
Update TableName set TransactionDate = DateTimeValue
Where TransactionID = 12
```